# Why I can't put the lable in one line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to plot the fitted line and add a label:

```py
plt.plot(Tem, fitK[0] * Tem + fitK[1], label = ('fitted kinetic energy \n $E\_{k}^{fitted}=$ ' + fun1), color = 'red')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Can I make the second and third rows appear on the same line?

Comment: ```import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(1,11,1)
y = np.arange(1,11,1)
plt.plot(x,y, label='incredibly long string that is broken here \n and nowhere else at all even with terms like $E_{k}^{fitted}=$ ' + 'or even other strings attached to it')
plt.legend()
plt.show()```
There is no second new line for me, no matter how long the string is. Does your `fun1` contain a `\n`?

Comment: I would need a minimal, reproducible example to understand what is going wrong as I cannot reproduce the problem. Feel free to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The fun1 is str(np.poly1d(np.polyfit(X, Y, 1))), and the output ' \n0.506 x - 0.514' do have '\n'. I did not realize that.

Comment: Okay, posted the comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = np.arange(1,11,1) 
y = np.arange(1,11,1) 
plt.plot(x,y, label='incredibly long string that is broken here \n and nowhere else at all even with terms like $E_{k}^{fitted}=$ ' + 'or even other strings attached to it') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

There is no second new line for me, no matter how long the string is. Does your `fun1` contain a `\n`?